# Self hosted webfonts: how to stop someone stealing them?

Tags: fonts, webfonts

If I self host bought web fonts is there anything I should do to stop someone stealing the fonts, or linking to the fonts from their site?

The only other post I can find about this is from six years ago. Is it now possible to protect bought web fonts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect webfonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470085/how-to-protect-webfonts)

Comment: Not really. The question and answers were posted six years ago. I'm wondering if there is now a way of doing this?